# Resources for learning non-linear Math

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I have a basic math background (ODE's, calculus), thermodynamics and mechanics. I have looked through books by Ilya Prigogine and most of the math went way past me.

What books or other resources would you recommend to help me begin making sense of Prigogines work?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about that author, but if I understand your question properly, you might want to visit your local college library and also explore the following list.

1. Nonlinear Dynamics And Chaos: With Applications To Physics, Biology, Chemistry, And Engineering (Studies in Nonlinearity) by Steven H. Strogatz (Jan 19, 2001)
2. Nonlinear Mathematics (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Thomas L. Saaty and Joseph Bram (Jun 17, 2010)
3. Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers (Oxford Texts in Applied and Engineering Mathematics) by Dominic Jordan and Peter Smith (Oct 11, 2007)
4. Modern Nonlinear Equations (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Thomas L. Saaty and Mathematics (Nov 2, 2011)
5. Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos (Texts in Applied Mathematics) by Stephen Wiggins (Nov 29, 2010)
6. Nonlinear Systems (Cambridge Texts in Applied Mathematics) by Philip G. Drazin (Jun 26, 1992)
7. Nonlinear Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems (Universitext) by F. Verhulst (Apr 3, 2006)
8. Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields (Applied Mathematical Sciences Vol. 42) by John Guckenheimer and Philip Holmes (Aug 1, 1983)
9. Chaos and Nonlinear Dynamics: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers [Paperback]
   Robert Hilborn (Author)
10. In the Wake of Chaos: Unpredictable Order in Dynamical Systems (Science and Its Conceptual Foundations series) by Stephen H. Kellert (Dec 15, 1994)
11. The Art of Modeling Dynamic Systems: Forecasting for Chaos, Randomness and Determinism (Dover Books on Computer Science) by Foster Morrison (Jan 24, 2008)
12. Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers: Linear and Nonlinear Systems (Dover Books on Mathematics) by Peter B. Kahn and Mathematics (Jun 14, 2004)
13. Fractals, Chaos, Power Laws: Minutes from an Infinite Paradise (Dover Books on Physics) [Paperback] Manfred Schroeder (Author), Physics (Author)
14. Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos, Second Edition (Pure and Applied Mathematics) by Stephen Smale, Morris W. Hirsch and Robert L. Devaney (Nov 5, 2003)
15. A First Course in Dynamics: with a Panorama of Recent Developments by Boris Hasselblatt and Anatole Katok (Jun 23, 2003)
16. Chaotic Dynamics: An Introduction [Paperback] Gregory L. Baker (Author), Jerry P. Gollub (Author)
17. Chaos in Dynamical Systems [Paperback] Edward Ott (Author)
18. Differential Equations: A Dynamical Systems Approach: Ordinary Differential Equations (Texts in Applied Mathematics) (Pt 1) [Hardcover] John H. Hubbard (Author), Beverly H. West (Author)
19. Differential Equations and Their Applications : An Introduction to Applied Mathematics (Texts in Applied Mathematics, Vol. 11) [Hardcover] Martin Braun (Author)
20. Understanding Nonlinear Dynamics (Texts in Applied Mathematics) [Hardcover] Daniel Kaplan (Author), Leon Glass (Author)

Additionally, you might also look online where some universities have open courseware, for example:

1. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-006j-nonlinear-dynamics-i-chaos-fall-2006/
2. http://www.deas.harvard.edu/climate/eli/Courses/APM147/2004fall/
3. http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/spring2009/physics221a/LECTURES/221_COURSE.pdf

Comment: Awesome bibliography! $$+ \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)$$